# Need help to Change Table Colors in PHP code using SQL query values with number range

Tags: php, html, sql, sqlite

This is a partial of the code I have on my script. I have tried to make the backgrounds change color depending on the values and can't get it to read the arrays correct. Placing the conditions outside the while or inside the while returns same results when printed.

If the value is 100, the color should be RED
If the value is above 49, the color will be yellow
If the value is 0 to 49, the color will be green

Will appreciate if someone would find how the BILLED_TO_DATE_PERCENTAGE would change depending on number range when SQL read pulls data.

```
$counter = 1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
    if($BILLED_TO_DATE_PERCENTAGE = 100)
        {
        $tdStyle='background-color:red;';
        } 
    else 
        {
        if($BILLED_TO_DATE_PERCENTAGE > 79)
            {
            $tdStyle='background-color:yellow;';
            }
        else
            {
            $tdStyle='background-color:green;';
            }
        }

    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td bgcolor=#001F25>" . "<b>" . "<font color=WHITE>" . $counter . "</font>" . "</b>" . "</td>";
    echo "<td bgcolor=#00353F>" . "<b>" . "<font color=WHITE>" . $row['NUMBER'] . "</font>" . "</td>";
    echo "<td bgcolor=#00353F>" . "<b>" . "<font color=WHITE>" . $row['PROJECT'] . "</font>" . "</td>"; 
    echo "<td style=\"$tdStyle\">" . "<b>" . "<i>" . $row['BILLED_TO_DATE_PERCENTAGE'] . "</i>" . "</b>" . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>"; 
    $counter++; //increment counter by 1 on every pass
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Where is `$BILLED_TO_DATE_PERCENTAGE` coming from? Use echo to verify its value before your if condition.

Comment: the Value $BILLED_TO_DATE_PERCENTAGE is a row in the Database that contains a value from 0 to 100 when the project is completed. First value is 100 so it prints RED, all other values are different numbers but table keeps printing RED instead of Yellow or Green. The If condition only picks up first value from the first row it reads in the SQL table.

Comment: if $BILLED_TO_DATE_PERCENTAGE = 100 , you are using just one "=",  you need to use ==

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a typo in there:

```
 if($BILLED_TO_DATE_PERCENTAGE = 100)
```

should be

```
 if ($row['BILLED_TO_DATE_PERCENTAGE'] == 100)
```

Use this form to avoid the same error again:

```
 if (100 == $row['BILLED_TO_DATE_PERCENTAGE'])
```

For color mapping, I think you could more easily use an array. This will allow to more easily maintain changes in the color requirements.

```
$colors = array(
    100 => '#ff0000',
    60  => '#ff77aa',
    0   => '#0000ff',
);

foreach ($colors as $limit => $color) {
    if ($row['FIELD'] >= $limit) {
        break;
    }
}
// Now $color will contain the desired color
// NOTICE: even if the last value is BELOW the last limit, $color
// will still contain the last color value. If this is undesired,
// add something like -99999 => 'last color' as the last line.
// The $color array MUST be kept sorted in descending key order.
```

A long way down that road, you might find it useful to write those colors in a .INI file using the PHP functions to read ini files:

```
[colors]
; You can use CSS codes if this goes into HTML.
0  = black
20 = green
60 = yellow
80 = red
100 = #c00000
```

So you would have something like

```
$CONFIG = parse_ini_file('config.ini', true);
krsort($CONFIG['colors']);
```

which can (perhaps!) even be "maintained" by the end user(s).

Comment: Thank you LSemi, this is exactly what I noticed after long period of days working with the script. Saw the mistake as soon when Dave questioned the value. Thank you for the ==. Didn't know and also fixed.

Comment: @AllanCruz you're welcome. A word of advice: I have dabbled with this kind of things for way too long, and almost always the requirements have changed from "three colors" to "five" to "six" to again "three", and if you do that with IF's, you'll pretty soon get crazy. At least, I certainly did. So I'd **strongly** advise using an array.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are good that the column in your database is not all upper case. You also aren't retrieving that value from the row after it is retrieved from the database.

```
$counter = 1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $percentage = $row['BILLED_TO_DATE_PERCENTAGE'];
    if($percentage == 100) {
        $tdStyle='background-color:red;';
    } elseif ($percentage > 49) {
        $tdStyle='background-color:yellow;';
   } else {
        $tdStyle='background-color:green;';
   }
   echo "<tr>"; 
   echo "<td bgcolor=#001F25>" . "<b>" . "<font color=WHITE>" . $counter . "</font>" . "</b>" . "</td>";
   echo "<td bgcolor=#00353F>" . "<b>" . "<font color=WHITE>" . $row['NUMBER'] . "</font>" . "</td>";
   echo "<td bgcolor=#00353F>" . "<b>" . "<font color=WHITE>" . $row['PROJECT'] . "</font>" . "</td>"; 
   echo "<td style=\"$tdStyle\">" . "<b>" . "<i>" . $row['BILLED_TO_DATE_PERCENTAGE'] . "</i>" . "</b>" . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>"; 
   $counter++; //increment counter by 1 on every pass
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thank you Dave. I actually saw what I was missing. When you said where does $BILLED_TO_DATE_PERCENTAGE come from, I noticed I was using it as a value and not locating the $row['BILLED_TO_DATE_PERCENTAGE'] declared to find the result. Finally got this working. Thank you alot!

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. [Here's how](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/379718) and [here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), then return here and do the same with the tick/checkmark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!

Answer (score 0):

It could be better to create a function to do that just to put the code more organized. And be careful with the "=", in your code the fist condition you were using just one "=", to compare you need to use "==":

```
function Changecolor($percentage){
    if ($percentage == 100) {
            return 'background-color:red;';
    } else {
       if ($percentage > 49) {
               return 'background-color:yellow;';
        } else {
           return 'background-color:green;';
       } 
     }
 }    

 echo "<table>";
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
        echo "<tr>"; 
        echo "<td bgcolor=#001F25>" . "<b>" . "<font color=WHITE>" . $counter . "</font>" . "</b>" . "</td>";
        echo "<td bgcolor=#00353F>" . "<b>" . "<font color=WHITE>" . $row['NUMBER'] . "</font>" . "</td>";
        echo "<td bgcolor=#00353F>" . "<b>" . "<font color=WHITE>" . $row['PROJECT'] . "</font>" . "</td>"; 
        echo "<td style=".Changecolor($row['BILLED_TO_DATE_PERCENTAGE']).">" . "<b>" . "<i>" . $row['BILLED_TO_DATE_PERCENTAGE'] . "</i>" . "</b>" . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>"; 
        $counter++; //increment counter by 1 on every pass
      }
 echo "</table>";
```